# HIVE: Reverse order search

Tags: search, hive

I have a huge hive table with potentially millions of rows in which i wish to do a search through on the basis of a column (the column has time in human readable format). Basically i wish to search for only the recently inserted rows (say in the past 1 hour).

When i do a `select * from table name`, it always returns results from the start. I have to compare the time for each row until i reach the recently inserted row which is a time consuming task. Is there any way i can do a search from the last row and moving in the reverse direction until i reach a particular row?

Additional info: the table is partitioned based on dates.

Comment: Can you convert your time to a timestamp? (using `unix_timestamp()` with a pattern) and then just limit your search to the timestamp of "now-1 hour"?

Comment: I'm really confused as to why this question couldn't be solved by adding a `where` clause to the query.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 Because the time is in human readable format (dd-MM-yy HH-mm-ss.SSS zzz) and comparison between two such dates (with timezone included) is not directly possible. The comparison would by default be lexicographical instead of a logical time based comparison.

Comment: So just as @Jcl said, covert it to unix time and search for it in a where clause ...

Comment: I didn't understand what @Jcl meant "using unix_timestamp with a pattern?" What is the pattern here?

Comment: The pattern is what you just described to me in your response, i.e. `dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz`

Comment: The thing is i do not want to insert another column that is the unix timestamp of the equivalent human readable date time. I require a solution that is purely hive based. Can i write a hive query to do this conversion such that i can specify start and end times?

Comment: @Jcl Thanks! The solution you suggested works (Although i still need to optimize it for tables with more than 1 million rows). Can you please suggest any optimization and post your previous response and the optimization as an answer so that i can accept it and the bounty gets awarded?

Comment: Added an answer, although I'm afraid there's no good news with the optimization part (at least that I know of, but I'm definitely no database -and much less apache hive- expert) :-/

Comment: Maybe you should `order by` the time row changed.

Comment: @luoluo that woldn't work on strings with user-readable text, that's basically the problem here

Comment: Then covert the time column to something comparable. Show some sample data of the time column.

Comment: Yes, that's what I stated in my answer, but he said in the comments he didn't want to change the column or insert a new one, so I don't know... maybe the OP needs to be more specific about what can be done and what can't :-)

Comment: the `convert` only appear in `select part`, so there is no `change the column or insert a new one`.

Comment: @luoluo yes, we are past that already, now we are trying to optimize it. If you need to run a function a string, the where clause (or order, or whatever other) is quite unoptimized for a table of 1+ million rows... if it was directly comparable, an index would help there, but having to use a function to convert it renders it useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `where` clause including a `unix_timestamp()` function with the pattern you are storing your time with, and just select those rows which are of interest to you (in your case, those with a greater timestamp than "now - one hour").

I don't see how you can optimize this if you are using a string column. If you can modify your table it'd be wise to have a timestamp or date column and make an index to speed up the query, but if you have to use functions on string columns, an index would be of no help here, I'm afraid.

Code or SQL can't optimize a bad design choice (using string columns for data where you have to make any kind of calculation in, is just a bad choice). If there's a date column where you partition your table with, you could add a clause to use only today's date (or today and yesterday if you are interested in "now - x hours"), but that's about it.